# Use pandas style using comma as decimal separator

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I want to use pandas style, and to use comma as decimal separator.

Take this dataframe for example:

```
tb = pd.DataFrame({"Variable": [5, 4.5, 4.8, 4.7], "std_err": [1, .06, .09, .17]}, 
                index = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D'])
```

|  | Variable | std_err |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 5.0 | 1.00 |
| Group B | 4.5 | 0.06 |
| Group C | 4.8 | 0.09 |
| Group D | 4.7 | 0.17 |

I tried this:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
pd.set_option("float_format", locale.str)

tb = pd.DataFrame({"Variable": [4.9853, 4.5345, 4.8542, 4.7234], 
                   "std_err": [.9234, .0676, .0917, .1784]}, 
                   index = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D'])
tb.style.bar()
```

But I expected to see commas as decimal separators and the style bars, rather I've got this a table formatted with style, but with locale ignored.

Can I have both? The table formatted with style (bars, colors etc) and with commas as decimal separators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward fix is to specify the `decimal` parameter of [`Styler.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format):

```
tb.style.format(decimal=',').bar()
```

[image: formatted with decimal as comma and bar]

Other alternatives include setting the `formatter` to a function like [`locale.str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.str)

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')

tb.style.format(formatter=locale.str).bar()
```

[image: dataframe styled using locale string format and bar]

Or [`locale.format_str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.format_string):

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')

tb.style.format(
    formatter=lambda x: locale.format_string('%.6f', x)
).bar()
```

[image: DataFrame formatted with 6 decimal precision and decimal point as comma with overlayed bar chart]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, the first solution didn't work here... (TypeError: format() got an unexpected keyword argument 'decimal') the other did the job nicely!

Comment: Yeah. `decimal` is "New in version 1.3.0." But glad there was one that works for you!