# Comma as a decimal separator in pandas dataframe display

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to set for data frames to display floating point numbers with a comma as decimal separator. I tried to use:

```
pd.set_option("styler.format.decimal",',')
```

But is seems, that it does not affect display of data frame.
I know I can use

```
df.style.format(decimal=',')
```

But I would like to set comma as decimal separtar as default for displying all dataframes...
I use Pandas 2.0

Comment: What is your Pandas version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use pandas style using comma as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845270/use-pandas-style-using-comma-as-decimal-separator)